# Opening database in Pycharm for Django project

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, pycharm

I am working on a django project using pycharm. How do I view the data in my sqlite db. From sources I found online, I have to open View-Tools Windows-Database, but I don't have that option. Can anyone help? I barely starting using pycharm today, thanks[sqlite db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3muZS.png)

Comment: The database tab is located on the right side of PyCharm. From there, you should be able to configure your database connection. More on SQLite with Pycharm : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1):

The DB stuff is only available in the professional version.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

If you're a student (with a university email) you can get the entire Jetbrains suite for free [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/community/education/#students).

Comment: any workaround if I have the CE (community) version?

Comment: @gabefern Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading db browser for sqlite . Then in the finder of my copmuter, i opended the db sqlite using that db browser. Just in case for anyone that has CE version